# unable to access the clusterIP_service or Internet within a pod by using serviceName or domainName

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

i have `2 pods`(pod1,pod2) with `2 services`(service1 links pod1, service2 links pod2) in the same namespace.

Within pod1 i performed below testing. i entered into pod1 using `kubectl exec ...` and

- Invoked restapi exposed in pod2 using `wget pod2ipaddress` - success
- Invoked restapi exposed in pod2 using `wget service2ipaddress` - success
- Invoked restapi exposed in pod2 using `wget service2Name` - failure with message `Could not resolve host: pcgamesapp-service`
- `curl https://www.google.com` - failure with message `Could not resolve host: www.google.com`
- Executed below `nslookup` command , but received `connection timeout error` as shown in below screenshot
  [image]

**Setup**

- Initalised k8s cluster (v1.22.9) with 1 masterNode and 1 workerNode on `ubuntu 20.04` using `kubeadm` in AWS EC2 virtual machines
- `weavenet` plugin for networking

i tracked the `kube-dns` logs but the request information of `curl serviceName` doesnot showup in the `kube-dns` logs
`kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns`

i followed the steps mentioned in [dns-debugging-resolution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) documentation, but i'm not able to figure out a solution

From reading the previous answers i assume that there is some issue with `coredns` or `iptables` ...etc . But i'm unable to figure out a solution for this issue.
Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i received the solution from a member named `felix-dpg`(@fdpg in stackoverflow) through another platform. i have added the solution details below

The information related to "which ports has to be opened for master node and worker node" are in [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/ports-and-protocols/)

The [weavenet](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/) port details are in [this link](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/faq/#:%7E:text=The%20Weave%20Net%20daemon%20listens,be%20opened%20to%20other%20hosts.)

Initially i didnot open (6783,6784)TCP,(6783,6784)UDP ports for Weavenet and port 53 for UDP(to enable inter-communication among the nodes in the cluster). The issue which i reported in this question got resolved by opening the ports for Weavenet and UDP

**Ports opened for Master node**
[image]

**Ports opened for Worker node**
[image]

Please let me know if you have any doubts or concerns with the above details. Thank you